# Excel Macro to move data from one sheet to another is very slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance, export

`I get one excel with IDs and associated other IDs in outlined format.
For example
[image: Input]
in this image - *5647326* is the main ID and associated ID is *8798965*, they are grouped with outlines.

I have requirement where I need to transfer data from this sheet to other sheet in same workbook, in linear format - like in original excel we get main ID in one row and associated IDs in next row, in new sheet main ID and associated ID should be in same row, if there are multiple associated IDs then main ID should be added twice and 2 associated IDs in respective rows like in
[image: Output]

We have developed a macro that works fine but is very slow like for 500 lines it takes 4-5 mins.
Can anyone help as how I can improve performance of following macro (Starting the input sheet data from A6 as first 5 rows have generic information that can be skipped from transfer to other sheet :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
' ' MoveRows Macro ' 
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w

Dim lastrow As Long 
Dim lastcol As Long 
Dim i As Integer 
Dim iNewRow As Integer 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim cell As Range
Dim row As Long 
Dim crtLvl As Integer 
Dim rgRow As Range 
Dim orgSelect As Range

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row 
lastcol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'MsgBox lastrow

'Delete all worksheets other than Sheet1 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
For Each ws In Worksheets 
If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" 
Then ws.Delete 
End If 
Next 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Create a new worksheet 
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheet1).Name = "Export" 
With Sheets("Export") 
.Range("A1") = "ID" 
.Range("B1") = "Name" 
.Range("C1") = "Type" 
.Range("D1") = "Owner" 
.Range("E1") = "Task Status" 
.Range("F1") = "Associated Resource ID" 
.Range("G1") = "Associated Resource Name" 
.Range("H1") = "Associated Resource Type" 
.Range("I1") = "Associated Resource Owner" 
.Range("J1") = "Associated Resource Status"

.Range("A1:J1").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
End With

i = 6 
iNewRow = 2 
Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim Lr As Long 
Dim Lc As Long 
Dim FirstCell As Range
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Set FirstCell = Range("A6") 
Dim inp As Integer 
Dim iFirstLevelRow As Integer

With Sheet1 
For Each cell In .Range("a6", .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)) 
'rg2c = Range(FirstCell, .Cells(i, 1).Select) 
rangeName = i & ":" & i 
rg2c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(rangeName)

inp = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).OutlineLevel 

If i <= lastrow Then
   If inp = 1 Then
   iFirstLevelRow = cell.row
  
        i = i + 1
 End If
  If inp = 2 Then
  .Cells(iFirstLevelRow, 1).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 1)
        .Cells(iFirstLevelRow, 2).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 2)
        .Cells(iFirstLevelRow, 3).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 3)
           .Cells(iFirstLevelRow, 4).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 4)
           .Cells(iFirstLevelRow, 5).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 5)
           .Cells(iFirstLevelRow, 6).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 6)
  .Cells(cell.row, 1).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 7)
        .Cells(cell.row, 2).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 8)
        .Cells(cell.row, 3).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 9)
         .Cells(cell.row, 4).Copy Sheets("Export").Cells(iNewRow, 10)
        i = i + 1
        iNewRow = iNewRow + 1
 End If
 End If

Next

End With

Worksheets("Export").UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Export").UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `cell` variable tracks down every row but also every column in the range - however, *I believe* you're only interested in / working on - each row. So you're performing the inside of the loop multiple times per row which perhaps you don't want to do?

Comment: Instead of copying column by column with .`Cells` use a `Range` and do all the columns at once

Comment: If you just copy the text inside cells, I'd recommend not to use Copy but set the values. ToSheet.Cells(1,1).value = FromSheet.Cells(1,1).value.

Comment: Do you really need the `OutLine` evaluation? Aren't the rows containing "Task" in C:C column main IDs and the other ones associated IDs?

Comment: @CHill60 Thats the problem I tried storing one row in array and copy all columns at once but that is not working, I dont know for sure how to do all columns at once...

Comment: @FaneDuru Outlined sheet is the input given to me and for user reading a linear report is preferred

Comment: @lorenzalbert thanks for the suggestion, I am just copying text inside cell, I will try out using .values now and will update the results.

Comment: I do not care too much about the Outlined Sheet itself. I tried clarifying the next aspect: Isn't it correct co consider main IDs the one having "Task" in C:C column and the rest of lines being associated IDs? Not needing to evaluate at all The `OutLine` levers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your reply to my comment - here are ways of using a range. This includes the suggestion from @lorenz albert (upvoted)

```
Sub demo()

    'Method 1 - use the Range to copy/paste instead of column by column or row by row
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:I5").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:I4")

    'Method 2 - assign the values directly
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5:I6").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:I7").Value
    
    'Method 3 - use arrays as an intermediary - useful if you need to examine or amend the contents of any cells first
    Dim vArr As Variant
    vArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:I9").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A7:I8").Value = vArr

End Sub
```

Comment: I could use method 3 - using array my macro works perfectly. Thanks a lot and sorry for so late response.

Answer (score 2):

Please, test the next way. You did not answer my clarification question, so it assumes that the main tasks are the ones having "Task" in C:C column. It should be very fast even for large ranges to be processed. Using arrays and drop the processed array content at once, it works mostly in memory:

```
Sub ProcessTasks()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, destws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, iRow As Long, rg As Range
  Dim arr, arr1, arrTsk, arrIt, arrHd, arrFin, dKey, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  Set destws = ws.Next 'destination sheet (here, the next one)
  destws.UsedRange.Clear
  
  Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
  lastR = rg.Row 'last row (hidden rows included)
  
  arr = ws.Range("A2:E" & lastR).Value2
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 3) = "Task" Then
        arrTsk = Array(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5))
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = Array(arrTsk, Array(""))
        dKey = arr(i, 1)
    Else
        arrIt = dict(dKey)
        If Not IsArray(arrIt(1)(0)) Then
            arrIt(1)(0) = Array(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5))
            dict(dKey) = arrIt
        Else
            arr1 = arrIt(1)
            ReDim Preserve arr1(UBound(arr1) + 1)
            arr1(UBound(arr1)) = Array(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5))
            arrIt(1) = arr1:  dict(dKey) = arrIt
        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
  Next i
  
  ReDim arrFin(1 To iRow + 1, 1 To 10) 'redim the final array according to the determined number of rows (iRow)
  
  'Load headers array:
  arrHd = Split("ID,Name,Type,Owner,Task Status,Associated Resource ID,Associated Resources Name,Associated Resource Type, Associated Resource Owner,Associated Resource Status", ",")
  
  'load the final aray header:
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrHd)
    arrFin(1, i + 1) = arrHd(i)
  Next i
  
  'process the dictionary items:
  Dim k As Long, m As Long, j As Long: k = 1
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    For m = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i)(1))
        k = k + 1
        'fill the final array first 5 columns corresponding to the main IDs:
        For j = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i)(0))
            arrFin(k, j + 1) = dict.Items()(i)(0)(j): 'Stop
        Next j
        'fill the rest of the final array columns corresponding to associated IDs
        For j = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i)(1)(m))
            arrFin(k, j + 6) = dict.Items()(i)(1)(m)(j): 'Stop
        Next j
    Next m
  Next i
  
  'Drop the final array content, at once:
  With destws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value2 = arrFin
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```